# Autoshapes and charts flick like they're having a seizure when VBA code is run on Excel Dashboard

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a dashboard in excel for my work over the last 4 months. The workbook is well organized, by my estimation, with database sheets, "under the hood" calculation sheets and the top, user visible data exhibition sheets. Also, I have 5 VBA modules that perform several different tasks, mostly relating to control of what the users see on screen. In some cases, there are complex chains of macros that put the right numbers, autoforms and charts in the right places.

The thing is: whenever one of these chains goes off, my autoforms and charts quickly flick in and out of screen, even though i have the screen updating off when executing them. It is a very quick flicking that happens, but it happens all over my workbook, with all of my content. It's ok with the changing content, but it happens over some lined forms that I use accross all of my sheets, with hyperlinks for navigation.

Example:

[image]

Note that this happens in very quick succession, sometimes repeating several times before the code is finished running, kind of like a seizure. The problem does not affect the functionality, but is visually disturbing, and my boss would rather not having it. I have searched the internets and have not found anything useful, so any help is appreciated.

I'm using Office 2010 on windows XP.

Comment: Try putting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` int your code. I've had similar 'seizure' while manipulating data behind a chart because excel was recalculating the sheet each time. Don't forget to switch the calculation back to Automatic.

Comment: I've posted this on reddit and I received the response advising me to use this:
`Public Sub LudicrousMode(ByVal Toggle As Boolean)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not Toggle
    Application.EnableEvents = Not Toggle
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not Toggle
    Application.Calculation = IIf(Toggle, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    
End Sub `

Previously I was only disabling ScreenUpdating. The thing is I have a pair of procedures that Locked and Unlocked the user interactive sheets, which in turn toggled ScreenUpdating on and off inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using an adaptive code snippet to toggle or untoggle ScreenUpdating and Calculation, it goes like this:

`Public Sub LudicrousMode(ByVal Toggle As Boolean)
Dim LockStatus As Boolean`

```
LockStatus = Sheets("Aux").Range("B1").Value

If Toggle = LockStatus Then GoTo SKIP

Application.ScreenUpdating = Not Toggle
Application.EnableEvents = Not Toggle
Application.DisplayAlerts = Not Toggle
Application.Calculation = IIf(Toggle, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)

Sheets("Aux").Range("B1").Value = Toggle`
```

`SKIP:
End Sub`

It was able to stop the "seizures" for most of the subs, except for those with the hiding and unhiding of rows and columns. Any idea with that?